# Locally uniform and pointwise convergence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm writing my thesis and I'm struggling with a sequence of functions $F^n$ defined on $R^n$ with quadratic growth that converges locally uniform to a function $F$ with quadratic growth, too. Under which assumptions can I conclude that the convergence is pointwise? Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of locally uniform convergence?  From the definition I have in mind (uniform convergence in balls around points), pointwise convergence is automatic.

Comment: You're right, it's pretty trivial. Now it's clear.